# Why is this CSV conversion coming back as a single element in each array element

Tags: python, csv

Here is what I tried, so far:

```
import csv
print "Dennis"
with open('Example1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    # ... process CSV file contents here ...
    print reader
    try:
        for row in reader:
            #print row
            print row[0],   row[1],   row[2]    #FAILS HERE
    except csv.Error as e:
        #skip

print "ended"
```

The CSV lib seems to convert and package the converted data as follows.

```
['GB0002875804,ABIH RIAN TCO ORD,"191,560.00000"']
['GB0002374006,DIO ORD 28 101/108P,"440,274.00000"']
['GB00B03MLX29,ROY DUH ELL PLC,"310,437.00000"']
```

This is like multiple elements in a single element and a single element inside a single array element.  What gives?

I was hoping to get the conversion as follows.

```
[GB0002875804,ABIH RIAN TCO ORD,"191,560.00000"]
[GB0002374006,DIO ORD 28 101/108P,"440,274.00000"]
[GB00B03MLX29,ROY DUH ELL PLC,"310,437.00000"]
```

This way I have to extract the single element and then extract the coma separated values.  Is there a more direct way to convert to get the desired conversion as I showed above in the second data example without the single quotes package?

Many thanks,

Dennis

Comment: Great, now my code is mangled!  What's the beef with stackoverflow.  Is the stack overflowing???

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If it fails on print, are you sure that `row[1] - [2]` have values?

Comment: "FAILS" is not a problem description.

Comment: I was hoping that I could get the data in row[0]- row[2] so I can send the fields to the Table.  I get one single element per row instead of 3

Comment: When it "FAILS HERE", what happens? An exception? (If so, what exception, and what's the traceback?) Prints the wrong thing? (If so, what did it print, and what did you expect?) Something else?

Comment: There is only one element extracted from the row.  That means that all three fields are packed in one single array element.  What is the point of the reader in this case?

Comment: Abamert, row[3] is not defined!

Comment: @DKean: And? You're not printing `row[3]` anywhere, so who cares whether it's defined? And meanwhile, please answer my question. If it's an exception, tell us what exception and show the complete traceback. If it's printing the wrong thing, tell us what you expected and what you got. And so on. If we have to keep teasing out answers piece by piece, or read your mind, nobody will ever be able to answer you.

Comment: Abamert, Only row(0) has a value in it and that value is like this  `['GB00B16GWD56,VNE GRP,"7,254,981.00000"']`  That forces me to do more work to extract the three fields.  The CSV lib is suppoed to convert this to an array, a 2D array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the csv reader by using csvsniffer. The result is the entire line comes through without being separated into a 1 element list. You then get an index error when you try and print (access) non-existing elements of `row`.

Just use the defaults and manually remove the `['` from the first element, and the comma and `']` from the last element. My code assumes there are no leading or trailing whitespace; strip those off it they are there.

So, with this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/dennis.csv
['GB0002875804,ABIH RIAN TCO ORD,"191,560.00000"']
['GB0002374006,DIO ORD 28 101/108P,"440,274.00000"']
['GB00B03MLX29,ROY DUH ELL PLC,"310,437.00000"']
['GB0008762899,BG GP PC OD G0.10,"486,049.00000"']
['GB0008762899,BG GUP C ORD P0.10,"504,867.00000"']
['GB0005405286,BC HL OR D0.50 (K),"1,751,079.00000"']
['GB0009252882,GAITHNE OD P0.25,"806,535.00000"']
['GB00B16GWD56,VNE GRP,"7,254,981.00000"']
```

This fixes your problem (as I understand it):

```
import csv

LoL=[]
with open('/tmp/Dennis.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            row[0]=row[0].replace("['","")
            row[2]=float(row[2].replace("']","").replace(',',''))
            LoL.append(row)
            print ''.join('{}[{}]:{} '.format('row',i,e) for i,e in enumerate(row))

    except (csv.Error, ValueError) as e:
        print 'something bad happened...\ndying now...\n',e

print LoL
```

Prints:

```
row[0]:GB0002875804 row[1]:ABIH RIAN TCO ORD row[2]:191560.0 
row[0]:GB0002374006 row[1]:DIO ORD 28 101/108P row[2]:440274.0 
row[0]:GB00B03MLX29 row[1]:ROY DUH ELL PLC row[2]:310437.0 
row[0]:GB0008762899 row[1]:BG GP PC OD G0.10 row[2]:486049.0 
row[0]:GB0008762899 row[1]:BG GUP C ORD P0.10 row[2]:504867.0 
row[0]:GB0005405286 row[1]:BC HL OR D0.50 (K) row[2]:1751079.0 
row[0]:GB0009252882 row[1]:GAITHNE OD P0.25 row[2]:806535.0 
row[0]:GB00B16GWD56 row[1]:VNE GRP row[2]:7254981.0 
[['GB0002875804', 'ABIH RIAN TCO ORD', 191560.0], ['GB0002374006', 'DIO ORD 28 101/108P', 440274.0], ['GB00B03MLX29', 'ROY DUH ELL PLC', 310437.0], ['GB0008762899', 'BG GP PC OD G0.10', 486049.0], ['GB0008762899', 'BG GUP C ORD P0.10', 504867.0], ['GB0005405286', 'BC HL OR D0.50 (K)', 1751079.0], ['GB0009252882', 'GAITHNE OD P0.25', 806535.0], ['GB00B16GWD56', 'VNE GRP', 7254981.0]]
```

Comment: I think that you have the proper correction of my mistake, Drewk. Zak gave a good idea on how to treat the row/col list format, but you figured out my error.  Thank you for that.  I never did this before and I thought that the sniffer would help when various irregular characters that can fall between the quotes.  Straight parsing can go haywire when you get lots of different folks posting CSVs.  So, now I have to figure out what sniffer really does.

Comment: It's primary use is to try t [deduce the delimiter](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0bacbab678ed/Lib/csv.py#l279) of a file where the delimiter is not known. It does this with only [moderate success](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-March/012604.html). If you know your delimiter, just use it directly when you set up the csv reader.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to itterate through the columns as well?  IE:

```
for row in reader:
          for col in row:
            print  col
```

Comment: Why? Besides the fact that this would print each column on a separate line, which he doesn't want, he's already printing all 3 columns (and in a .csv file, the number of columns is always constant). So what does this get him?

Comment: Wait a minute, this sounds right.  This is that answer.  I was not aware of the `col` reference.   Thank you ZAK you RACK!  I get it now.  The row is not an array, therefore the row has columns to access the fields...

Comment: @abarnet, we're not dealing with arrays, so you can't treat it like one.  Anyhow, that's how I've always done it (in combination with a counter to exclude the "CSV header" if there is one)  ..  It works for me, I don't see why it wouldn't work for DKean.

Comment: @Zak: I'm not sure what you mean by "not an array", but the thing that `csv.reader` returns for each row is a `list` of values, indexed by column number, which fits most people's definition of "array". (And if that weren't true, you probably wouldn't be able to iterate over it, either. If, for example, you were using a `DictReader`, which returns as `dict` instead of a `list`, this would just print all the column names instead of the values.)

Comment: And my fault was that I did not recognize it as a list.  This is the first time I try to use the CSV.  I wanted to use the CSV lib to avoid having to parse through the commas inside the quotes, as you can see in the data.  But thank you all and sorry for confusing you.  You guys are all great...  Thank you...